# Create foreign key on MySQL table takes forever with copy to tmp table

Tags: mysql, performance, foreign-keys, alter-table

I am trying to set a foreign key constraint on a `5.7 InnoDB` table with 30M+ rows.

It now already runs for 45 minutes on a quad core 64GB server. The processlist outputs the state `copy to tmp table` for the issued alter table command.

`InnoDB_buffer_pool_size` is set to 32G and has room.

Why does the system create a `tmp` table and can this somehow be increased in performance?

Comment: It has to check all the foreign keys to make sure they exist in the referenced table. That's going to take a while for 30M rows.

Comment: Do you know what  the options are  to speed up such a process in terms of settings and hardware? I assume only CPU power will help?

Comment: No idea. Try asking on [dba.se].

Comment: Please don't cross post.  When you do, at least have links between them.

Comment: Thank you for noting it. I followed your advise and posted a similar question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282706/how-to-speed-up-foreign-key-creation-in-mysql-for-large-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the time is being taken building an index for that foreign key. If you already had an index where the foreign key column(s) were the leftmost columns of the index, then it would use that index and not build a new one.

45 minutes doesn't sound like an unusual amount of time to build an index on such a large table. You haven't said what the data type of the foreign key column(s) are, so perhaps it's a large varchar or something and it is taking many gigabytes to build that index.

Perhaps your server's disk is too slow. If you're using non-SSD storage, or remote storage (like Amazon EBS), it's slow by modern standards.

The CPU cores isn't going to make any difference, because the work is being done in one thread anyway. A faster CPU speed would help, but not more cores.

At my company, we use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) to apply all schema changes or index builds. This allows clients to read and write the table concurrently, so it doesn't matter that it takes 45 minutes or 90 minutes or even longer. Eventually it finishes, and swaps the new table for the old table.

Comment: Thank you Bill for the insight. It eventually finished after 1:20h. It is a fk on 2 columns (tinyint,char(10)) running on SSDs. I hope a schema change of this kind will not occure so often.

Comment: We run dozens of schema changes of this type every week. By using an online schema change tool, we don't need to hope these schema changes are infrequent. We just run them as needed.

Comment: Does the creation of an FK necessitate checking the integrity of the links?

Answer (score 0):

Attention! This disables key checking so know what you are doing, in some cases this is not recommended, but can help many people so I think it's worth answering.

I had this problem this week, I have a client that still have mySQL 5.5, so I had to make it work. You just need to disable keys checking, as well as put your application down for maintenance (so you don't have any operations).
Before creating your FK or adding a column, use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;
```

Then run your command, my table with 1M rows took only 57 seconds.

Then you run:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS;
```